# Google maps place label language

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have already know that I can use the "language" attribute in the script tag to indicate the language that I want to display in the map. Like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en"></script>
```

In this way, all place label will be translated and displayed in English.

However, my supervisor is not happy with it. He wants the map to display place label in different languages like http://maps.google.com does when the "English" option is unchecked.
Like this photo:

[image: Google Maps label display]

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You can display a label over a country in the language you want using google's [Dynamic Icons](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons#scalable_pins)

Answer (score 1):

Although Google Maps API doesn't provide that function, I think this example is closed to your answer.

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-rtl

1. `<html dir="rtl">`
2. `language=ar`

[image]